# how to get product id from product on loaded product page using ajax and also get related product ids in shopify

Tags: shopify, laravel-5.5

when I click on product title then I want to get product id and then post product id to another URL and get related product id from the database.

```
<script>
var a = window.location.href;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            var id = data.product.id;
            console.log(id);// i got product id but how i post this id to another url and get related product id from database.
        }
    });
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Do this:

```
<script>
var a = window.location.href;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            var id = data.product.id;
            $.post("{{url('productIdApi')}}", {product_id: id}, function(result){
               //do whatever after response returns
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: @ Elisha when getting product id then I want to hit my laravel route and get related other ids from my database.

Comment: var a = window.location.href;
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                var id = data.product.id;
                $.post("/productIdApi", {product_id: id}, function(result){
                    console.log(result);
                    return result;
                });
            }
        });
productIdApi is my route Route::post("/productIdApi", productController@getProductId);

This function give error:-  "https://lekhraj-test-store.myshopify.com/proidapi 404 (Not Found)"

Comment: What is the full url to your Laravel route (e.g laravelapproute.com/productIdApi) ?

Comment: I have edited the answer with your url. Does it works now?

Answer (score 0):

The correct pattern for this is to render the product ID in Liquid to a JS variable. You understand Liquid has a JSON filter too right? So that means making an AJAX call to get the product info is redundant and a waste of time.

Once you have the product ID in JS world, you cannot securely use it to call for related products unless you use an App Proxy. Shopify ensures your Ajax callback comes from the shop and is legit. Calling back to your own database without that is silly as anyone can then hack your data for any other use.

Comment: then suggest me how to I getting related product id from my database. when a customer click on product title. then how to product open on the product page with their related product?

Comment: That is your job. I gave you a correct answer to your original question. You have the main parent product ID. Call your App Proxy with that ID, and get back JSON of every other related product according to your special App. Render whatever you want with the results.